# How to configure New Relic plugins to show a rate

Tags: newrelic, newrelic-platform

My mail server reports the total number of incoming and outgoing mail transfers each time I poll the API as well as retries, errors etc. I am successfully reporting this data as metrics to New Relic, but I can't figure out how to configure New Relic plugin dashboards to display the metrics in useful ways like error rates and average number of retries per email etc. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The New Relic platform does not have any way of doing calculations beyond the Min, Max, Average, Total, and Standard Deviation, on the metrics once they are received.

You'll need to do any [calculations](https://newrelic.com/docs/plugin-dev/metric-data-for-the-plugin-api#calculations) you want in the plugin agent. The Java and Ruby SDKs both have an "Epoch Counter" processor which will convert your "total count" values into rates conveniently. Take a look at the wikipedia examples agents [Java Wikipedia Example](https://github.com/newrelic-platform/newrelic_java_wikipedia_plugin) and [Ruby Wikipedia Example](https://github.com/newrelic-platform/newrelic_wikipedia_plugin)